# Black area on my 3d model. How would I fix this?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a coffee cup and then when I connected the grip to the main cup this happened.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all your Faces and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>N</kbd>  (Recalculate Normals)

These faces face the wrong direction, in fact they point towards the inside of the grip. This sometimes happens when you manually conect faces but it's no problem at all.

In case this doesn't work and some faces still point to the inside you can select those manualy and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd> , then select "Flip Normals".

Comment: Thank you. I will add you to be the official answer in 12 min. What is the shortcut for? Recalculate normals?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's recalculate normals. Btw you can also flip the individual normals of faces by selecting the ones you want to change, pressing Ctrl-F and select "Flip Normals".

Comment: @Quacksilber please check my comment under the question.

Comment: @LukeD yes, thats the same topic. So what shall I do now?